# RedisException when installing SilverStripe

Tags: php, redis, silverstripe

I've installed SilverStripe using composer but when I try and access the site I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RedisException' with message
>   'Connection closed' in
>   /var/www/silverstripe_test/framework/dev/install/install.php5 on line
>   31 RedisException: Connection closed in
>   /var/www/silverstripe_test/framework/dev/install/install.php5 on line
>   31

The error seems to occur when `session_start()` is called but I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your instance of PHP is set up to use Redis for sessions. Have a look in php.ini and, if present, change "session.save_handler = redis" to "session.save_handler = files". If you're using Apache you can also add "php_value session.save_handler redis" to .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks for this. Had a slightly unusual set up on the VM I'm using and this worked fine.